# C# - Capitalize in foreach

Tags: c#

I've got an issue with capitalizing a list of strings in a `foreach` statement. I'm pretty sure it is very simple, but actually I cannot see why it is not updating the strings in the list.
I have the following method:

```
public static string Capitalize(string fileName)
{
     TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
     List<string> splittedFileName = fileName.Split('_').ToList();
     splittedFileName.ForEach((file) => file = textInfo.ToTitleCase(file));
     return String.Join("_", splittedFileName);
}
```

First it splits provided a string by underscore into a `List`.
Then I thought I can use `foreach` to update each element (make the first letter uppercase).
I.e. I call the method this way:

```
var capitalized = Export.File.Capitalize("test_all_first_letters_uppercase");
```

If I debug the solution it updates the `file` variable, but the `List` entries are not being updated. So the return value of my example is

> test_all_first_letters_uppercase

but it should be

> Test_All_First_Letters_Uppercase

As I said, I'm sure it is a simple reason for it, but actually I cannot see it.

Comment: your ForEach function assigns a variable but then doesn't do anything with it - it doesn't append it to a new string, or update an existing one.

Comment: You're looking for `.Select`, not `.ForEach`. Your `file` is a local parameter, which is changed, and then discarded at the end of the call. The `List` intermediate is also unnecessary (you can call `.Select` directly on the `.Split`, and `.Join` directly on the resulting `IEnumerable`). This could even be a one-liner (`public static string Capitalize(string fileName) => String.Join("_", fileName.Split('_').Select(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase));`).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-6.0 "Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action<T> delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior."

Comment: @sergiol He did not do that. That would be if he did stuff like inserting into `splittedFileName` inside the lambda (`Action<>`) beginning with `(file) => ...`.

Comment: Just a heads up, i recently had an issue with this method `.ToTitleCase`. The method despite requiring the culture and language info actually only spit out correct format for the English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
splittedFileName.ForEach((file) => file = textInfo.ToTitleCase(file));
```

just assigns a by-value parameter (`file`) which has no effect. Note, it is *not* `ref string file`.

You can use `.ConvertAll` instead, or Linq. Examples:

```
var changed = splittedFileName.ConvertAll(file => textInfo.ToTitleCase(file));
// or:
var changed = splittedFileName.Select(file => textInfo.ToTitleCase(file));
```

In both cases, you can use the "method group" directly:

```
var changed = splittedFileName.ConvertAll(textInfo.ToTitleCase);
// or:
var changed = splittedFileName.Select(textInfo.ToTitleCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are use foreach, you are not actually updating the items in the list. You are just going through them and making an operation on each value in the list.

For your case, I suggest you use a for loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < mylist.Count(); index++)
{
     mylist[index] = TextInfo.ToTitleCase(mylist[index])
}
```

Comment: _"for loop"_ - indeed, sometimes _simpler is better._ +1

Comment: `.ToTitleCase` is a method of `TextInfo`, not `string`.

Comment: @MosGeo Yes, of course, I could have done a simple for loop, but I prefer one-liner-statements instead of multiple lines. But of course, your solution would work, too.

Answer (score 0):

In generalized case, you can try using *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
string demo = "it is a demo: a_b_c, ABC, aBc, abC";

// Capitalizes every first letter in the word
// It Is A Demo: A_B_C, ABC, ABc, AbC
string result = Regex.Replace(demo, @"(?:\b|_)\p{Ll}", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
```

Or if you are looking for a title case:

```
string demo = "it is a demo: a_b_c, ABC, aBc, abC";

// Capitalizes every first letter in the word
// It IS A Demo: A_B_C, ABC, Abc, Abc
string result = Regex.Replace(
  demo, 
 @"(?:\b|_)\p{L}+", 
  m => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m.Value));
```